# NodeJS save data in Firebase but no retrieve data

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm having difficulty retrieving data from Firebase through NodeJS. Although in the code it is possible to save data, I am not able to recover the data from the database. Why is this happening?

```
var firebase = require("firebase-admin");

// Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://<MY URL>.firebaseio.com/'
});

var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("bd/");

ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    var back=snapshot.exportVal();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(back));
})
```

Comment: Crazy guess: `"bd/"` should be `"db/"` ?

Comment: The directory is called "bd" haha @DanGetz

Comment: What do you get if console log the snapshot

Comment: Nothing =\ @DanGetz

Comment: With the same "ref" are you able to write data

Comment: try adding `firebase.database.enableLogging(true)` and see what comes up (maybe it is an authentication problem)

Comment: Did not work @DanGetz

Comment: Maybe console log `db` and `firebase`, possibly the `require` failed. Is this running from the same location as the writing script?

Comment: Perhaps your program exits before the event can fire?